# Drools: Strange behaviour of a String global variable

Tags: java, drools

The situation is easy. I created a rules file:

```
package org.domain.rules;
dialect "mvel"
import eu.ohim.fsp.core.configuration.domain.xsd.Section;

global java.lang.String sectionName;

rule "rule 1"
salience 1000
when
    Section($name : nameOfTheSection)
    eval(sectionName == null)
then
    System.out.println("Section: " + $name+ "("+$name.length()+")");
    System.out.println("Section Name: " + sectionName + "("+sectionName.length()+")");
    System.out.println("Mark Details: " + sectionName.equals(null));
end
```

And before firing the rules I added the Section object with a valid `coreName` and the globals:

```
public void fireInserted(Section section1) {
    kstateful.insert(section1);
    kstateful.setGlobal("sectionName", new String("markudetails"));
    kstateful.fireAllRules();
}
```

The result is:

```
Section: markudetails(12)
Section Name: markudetails(12)
Mark Details: false
```

QUESTION: How can it be possible? in **when** part is null and in **then** part is not null!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Global vars are not a part of the knowledge base, but a separate channel to push some context into the rule execution. It is not appropriate to use them in a `when` clause. The exact reason why it was `null` in your case may be hard to trace, since rule activation is completely decoupled from rule execution. The variable may simply not be bound at `when` clause evaluation time, but is bound at `then` clause execution time.

To summarize: don't use globals in a `when` clause, that's not what they are for.

Your problem has an easy general solution: you can insert a configuration object into the knowledge. That object can have your desired "sectionName" property which you will then find easy to test in a `when`.

As an aside, it is meaningless to test for `object.equals(null)` -- this can never produce `true`. There is also no need to use `new String("markudetails")`. Instead use just `"markudetails"`.

Comment: First of all: thanks! But, think about inserting in the knowledge more than one Section and, before firing the rules, selecting wich Section I want to test in the rules... How to do it? That's the meaning of the global variable sectionName.

Comment: Instead of answering in the comment, I improved my answer.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about doing that. Thanks!